# Shell Script unclear usage of " : "

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop

I have been trying to alter an old Shell Script for my project. I have done some researching but the usage of `:` in shell script but is quite unclear to me.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/dir1/dir2/dir3

FILES=../lib/*

CLASSPATH=.:../conf/

for f in $FILES
do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$f
done

echo $CLASSPATH
```

What are they trying to do here, is it looking for same named files in both directories and assigning them to `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: It is a literal `:`, i.e. the paths in `CLASSPATH` are separated by a `:`

Comment: Of course, this is better done with `CLASSPATH=.:/home/dir1/dir2/conf$(printf ":%s" /home/dir1/dir2/lib/*)`

Comment: `printf` or not an array here would be *much* safer. That said with an array one could also use `$(IFS=:; echo "${arr[*]}")`.

Answer (score 6):

`:` is a separator for the CLASSPATH.

Your script basically:

1. Sets the current directory to `/home/dir1/dir2/dir3`
2. Assigns `../lib/*` to `FILES`
3. Assigns `.` (the current directory) and `../conf` to `CLASSPATH` (separated with the `:`)
4. For every file in `FILES` sets the `CLASSPATH` to itself (to keep the old value) and append the path of the found file (again separated with the `:`)

Comment: thanks for the edit @arco444 :) english isn't my native language :D

Answer (score 1):

`:` is separator.

So what they're doing is get all the file in the directory `../lib`, and append them all to `CLASSPATH` by for loop.